# Access HTMLAttributes using script setup

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

So I have an Input component, and I would like to inherit all the default Input Attributes, this is my script

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
import { defineProps, InputHTMLAttributes } from "vue";

interface Props extends InputHTMLAttributes {
  label?: string;
}

defineProps<Props>();
</script>
```

I would like to know what am I supposed to put in my  tag to get the attributes. This is my template so far:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <span v-show="label">{label}</span>
    <input {?????} />
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Vue.js version>=3.3**

You can disable the attribute inheritance using the `defineOptions` macro :

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
import { InputHTMLAttributes } from "vue";

interface Props extends InputHTMLAttributes {
  label?: string;
}

defineProps<Props>();
defineOptions({ inheritAttrs: false })
</script>
```

**version < Vue3.3**

Add another script tag in which make `inheritAttrs:false` then bind `$attrs` to the input tag :

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
import { InputHTMLAttributes } from "vue";

interface Props extends InputHTMLAttributes {
  label?: string;
}

defineProps<Props>();
</script>
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
export default defineComponent({
  inheritAttrs:false
})
<template>
  <div>
    <span v-show="label">{label}</span>
    <input v-bind="$attrs" />
  </div>
</template>
</script>
```